# Python construct BFS

Tags: python

I have found many `BFS` example codes online, however, the input was not the same format as I have and output was not as expected.

I have a list of nodes `nodesList`, each node object has a node `id` and contains all `id` of its neighbour nodes in `neighboursList`. And now I want to construct a `BFS` using `nodesList`. As I know that calculation can be done and a `BFS` is constructed if I know:

- Which nodes are in each level of the `BFS` [level 1: root, etc]
- The parent node of each node in the `BFS`
- The child nodes of each node in the `BFS`
- The node `BFS` node `id` of each node in the `BFS`

So I created another class called `BFSnode`, which stores the info I need. Although I can always find out the first two levels, as I don't know how large the input graph will be, I am confused how can I find of these dynamically using recursion. As I am not familiarized with dynamic programming and recursion, it would be appreciated if someone could help me out. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

To do a breadth first search you do not need to use recursion or dynamic programming.

Breadth first search typically uses a Queue data structure:
1. Start by adding the root node, or the node you want to start the search from to a queue.
2. While there are nodes in the queue, first dequeue the next node. Process it however you need to and enqueue its children.
3. The search ends when the queue is empty.

Rough code (untested):

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        self.children = []

def breadth_first_search(root):
    next_nodes = Queue()
    next_nodes.enqueue(root)

    while not next_nodes.empty():
        cur_node = next_nodes.dequeue()

        # Do something with cur_node

        for child in cur_node.children:
            next_nodes.enqueue(child)
```

I've assumed the existence of a Queue object that supports enqueue, dequeue, and empty which is not a builtin in python. You can write your own, use a list, or use collections.deque with append() and popleft() instead of enqueue and dequeue.

I've also assumed the graph does not have cycles. It looks like you're working with trees so this is probably a safe assumption.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but the graph has cycle.